# How can i handle that: log.write len([name

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've got a problem. I dont know how to "connect"  log.write and len
Its about the 10th line

```
import os
import os.path
import time


DIR = '/home/richard/DB/'

#while a != 0:
log = open("logfile.log","wt")
log.write len([name for name in os.listdir(DIR) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(DIR, name))])
log.close()
```

Comment: `log.write(len(...))`

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/richard/db1.py", line 13, in <module>
    log.write(len([name for name in os.listdir(DIR) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(DIR, name))]))
TypeError: expected a string or other character buffer object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use :

```
log.write(str(len([name for name in os.listdir(DIR) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(DIR, name))])))
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/richard/db1.py", line 13, in <module>
    log.write(len([name for name in os.listdir(DIR) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(DIR, name))]))
TypeError: expected a string or other character buffer object

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Small syntax error

```
import os
import os.path
import time


DIR = '/home/richard/DB/'

#while a != 0:
log = open("logfile.log","wt")
log.write(len([name for name in os.listdir(DIR) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(DIR, name))]))
log.close()
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/richard/db1.py", line 13, in <module>
    log.write(len([name for name in os.listdir(DIR) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(DIR, name))]))
TypeError: expected a string or other character buffer object

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a string to log.write

```
log.write("{}".format(len([name for name in os.listdir(DIR) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(DIR, name))]))
```

or

```
log.write(str(len([name for name in os.listdir(DIR) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(DIR, name))]))
```